# ¿Por que mi Reporte PDF hecho en JasperReport se muestra en blanco cuando ejecuto mi app java?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar mi reporte pdf desde mi aplicación Java. He creado el Reporte con JasperStudio 6.20.6, he creado parámetros y campos que coincidan con los nombres de las variables y claves que están en mis clases Java, pero aun así el reporte se muestra en blanco, solo una hoja blanca sin mostrar los datos.
[image: Se puede ver los campos y los parámetros en el reporte con la sintaxis adecuada]

Ahora les muestro el código. Primero creé un HasMap  con sus respectivas claves y valores, ademas use un forEch para imprimir y verificar que realimente esté lleno (Imprime cada valor correctamente).

```
 HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("cliente", cliente);
    parametros.put("cedula", cedulaCliente);
    parametros.put("correo", correoCliente);
    parametros.put("telefono", telefonoCliente);
    parametros.put("direccion", direccionCliente);
    parametros.put("modificacion", ultimaModificacionCliente);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Valores del parametro");
    for (Object valor : parametros.values()) {
        
        System.out.println(valor);
    }
```

Luego hice una consulta a la base de datos (Sqlite) para obtener el numero de filas, es decir, obtener el numero de filas que tengan equipos según la cedula del cliente.

```
try {
        Connection conexion = Conectar.conectar();

        // Consulta para Obtener el numero de filas segun la cedula.
        PreparedStatement psCount = conexion.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM equipos WHERE cedulaCliente = ?");
        psCount.setString(1, cedula);

        ResultSet rsCount = psCount.executeQuery();
        int filas = 0;
        if (rsCount.next()) {
            filas = rsCount.getInt(1);
        }
```

Después, hice la consulta para obtener los datos de los equipos del cliente en cuestion, por ejemplo, datos como: tipo de equipos, marca... entre otros y lo guarde en un array bidimencional.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT tipo, marca, modelo, serie, fechaIngreso, ultimo, estatus, "
                + "ultimaFecha FROM equipos WHERE cedulaCliente = ?");
        ps.setString(1, cedula);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rmd = rs.getMetaData();

        // Obtener el número de columnas
        int columnas = rmd.getColumnCount();
        
        System.out.println("Filas: " + filas + " Columnas: " + columnas);

        // Creacion y llenado del arreglo segun los datos de las Consultas.
        String arreglo[][] = new String[filas][columnas];
        for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                arreglo[i][j] = rs.getString(j + 1);
            }
        }
```

Luego, cree una Lista de objetos  para crear un JRBeanCollectionDataSource con dicha lista.

```
 ReporteInformacionCliente informacion;
        List<ReporteInformacionCliente> fuenteDeDatosReporte = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            informacion = new ReporteInformacionCliente(arreglo[i][0],
                    arreglo[i][1], arreglo[i][2], arreglo[i][3],
                    arreglo[i][4], arreglo[i][5], arreglo[i][6],
                    arreglo[i][7]);
            fuenteDeDatosReporte.add(informacion);
        }
        
        System.out.println(fuenteDeDatosReporte.get(0).getEstatus() + " "
        + fuenteDeDatosReporte.get(0).getFechaIngreso());
        
        // Creacion y llenado del reporte.

        String path = "src/main/resources/InformacionCliente.jasper";
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource fuente = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                fuenteDeDatosReporte);
```

El arreglo se usa para pasar los datos mediante el constructor a la clase  ReporteInformacionCliente , que se las mostrare al final.

Después hice el siguiente código para crear y llenar el reporte:

```
try {
            
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path,parametros, fuente);
            JasperViewer vista = new JasperViewer(print, false);
            vista.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            vista.setVisible(true);
            
        } catch (JRException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en crear Reporte: " + e);
        }
```

Destaco que en la ejecución no me lanza ninguna excepción, ya he revisado de todo y nada.

Para terminar les muestro la Ultima clase que se usa para crear la lista de Objetos, me asegure que cada variable coincida con los nombres de los campos en el reporte.

```
public class ReporteInformacionCliente {

String tipo,marca,modelo,serie,fechaIngreso,ultimoEnModificar,estatus,
        ultimaFechaModificar;

public ReporteInformacionCliente(String tipo, String marca, String modelo, String serie, String fechaIngreso, String ultimoEnModificar, String estatus, String ultimaFechaModificar) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.serie = serie;
    this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
    this.ultimoEnModificar = ultimoEnModificar;
    this.estatus = estatus;
    this.ultimaFechaModificar = ultimaFechaModificar;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getModelo() {
    return modelo;
}

public void setModelo(String modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
}

public String getSerie() {
    return serie;
}

public void setSerie(String serie) {
    this.serie = serie;
}

public String getFechaIngreso() {
    return fechaIngreso;
}

public void setFechaIngreso(String fechaIngreso) {
    this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
}

public String getUltimoEnModificar() {
    return ultimoEnModificar;
}

public void setUltimoEnModificar(String ultimoEnModificar) {
    this.ultimoEnModificar = ultimoEnModificar;
}

public String getEstatus() {
    return estatus;
}

public void setEstatus(String estatus) {
    this.estatus = estatus;
}

public String getUltimaFechaModificar() {
    return ultimaFechaModificar;
}

public void setUltimaFechaModificar(String ultimaFechaModificar) {
    this.ultimaFechaModificar = ultimaFechaModificar;
}
```

}

He verificado la lista, el arreglo y otras cosas mas y realmente están llenos de manera correcta.

Les agradezco su Valiosa respuesta :)

Comment: No necesitas marear tanto a los datos, intenta crear la fuente directamente desde el ResultSet, algo así: `JasperFillManager.fillReport( path, parametros, new JRResultSetDataSource(rs) )`.

Comment: Ohhh, muchas gracias, no sabía que se podía hacer eso,  soy nuevo en esto de jasperReport. Muchas gracias 